# Session gets expired using third party dll's for pdf publishing

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, dotnetnuke, winnovative

The Scenario:

I have a situation where I need to pass some session variables to an ASPX page, inside a DNN module. This page is then transferred to [Winnovative's PDF publishing component's](http://www.winnovative-software.com/) in the form of a byte array. The component returns a PDF document in the result, furthermore that PDF document is then emailed to the customer.

The Problem:

The session gets expired when the ASPX page is called (hosted as a part of DNN web project on IIS) to pass it to Winnovative. It was noticed that the session expired when ever I request the page (by any means) and a new session on that page is created.

Is there any workaround (without involving a database) that I can access those session variables (it is a dataset) from that particular ASP.NET page?

Answer (score 2):

There was a known issue with calling non-DNN ASPX pages in DotNetNuke 5.6.1 which was fixed with 5.6.2. You might want to try upgrading to 5.6.2 and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: More info on the 5.6.1 issue: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/3015/Just-let-ASP-Net-handle-it.aspx

Comment: Cannot do that as this is to be done on the older version....sorry I didn't mentioned that earlier.

Comment: The issue linked above is unlikely to be related, it most likely would prevent you from calling the non-DNN page at all.  If the call to the page works then the in-process session should also be intact (DNN ignores session entirely).  My guess is your session cookie is lost.  Is the called page in a different domain like  pdf.mydomain.com?  Or the call changes from www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com?